# Saving header from CSV file using `numpy.genfromtxt()`

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, genfromtxt

I'm using `numpy.genfromtxt()` to read in a CSV file, and I'd like to save the header separately from the data below the header.

I know that the `skip_header=1` parameter allows me to skip the header, but, in that case, the header is lost, but I'd like to save it. I tried using the `skip_footer` parameter such that it would skip everything *below* the header and keep only the header by setting `skip_footer` equal to one less than the length of the CSV file or `skip_footer=(len('filename.csv')-1)`. The code runs but it doesn't give the right output. Somehow, `numpy.genfromtxt()` doesn't count the rows of the CSV file in the way that I'm imagining.

```
header = numpy.genfromtxt('filename.csv', delimiter=',', skip_footer=(len('filename.csv')-1))
```

I expected to get just the header as a 1-D NumPy array, instead I get something resembling the whole array:

```
[[      nan       nan       nan ...       nan       nan       nan]
 [2.016e+03 1.000e+00 1.000e+00 ... 1.165e+01 6.999e+01 1.000e+00]
 [2.016e+03 1.000e+00 1.000e+00 ... 8.000e+00 5.430e+01 1.000e+00]
 ...
 [2.016e+03 6.000e+00 3.000e+01 ... 0.000e+00 4.630e+01 2.000e+00]
 [2.016e+03 6.000e+00 3.000e+01 ... 8.750e+00 5.255e+01 1.000e+00]
 [2.016e+03 6.000e+00 3.000e+01 ... 8.880e+00 5.822e+01 1.000e+00]]
```

I want to keep just what's in the top row of `nan`s.

Comment: `len('filename.csv')-1` is 11.  Default `dtype` is `float`.

Comment: Use of `maxrows` makes more sense the `skip_footer` (which requires reading the whole file).

Comment: Thanks, @hpaulj, that worked. You just have to be careful to specify the `dtype` parameter as `dtype=str` in this case. See answer below.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48706350/1021819 for a clever use of `json.dumps()` for populating of such a header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
header = np.genfromtxt('filename.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=str, max_rows=1)
print(header)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['pickup_year' 'pickup_month' 'pickup_day' 'pickup_dayofweek'
 'pickup_time' 'pickup_location_code' 'dropoff_location_code'
 'trip_distance' 'trip_length' 'fare_amount' 'fees_amount' 'tolls_amount'
 'tip_amount' 'total_amount' 'payment_type']
```